# Display query image from a classifier

Tags: matlab

So I used the following codes for image recognition.

Everything worked, until I tried to display the query image with the matched image in the classifier.

Basically, I want to display the image am trying to recognize, beside the matched image...but it displays the query image and a blank graphical plot, with the error stated at the bottom. How do I display please?

Additionally, my trainingSet folder of original images contains sub folders labeled 0-9. So the predict line of code, NairaLabel actually predicts to match my query image to the right folder as a variable, but I want it displayed.

```
 [imname,impath]=uigetfile({'*.jpeg;*.jpg;*.png'});
  notes=imread([impath,'/',imname]);

 %preprocessing
 %resize image
 LoadIm;

 % Extract HOG features and HOG visualization

 [hog_4x4, vis4x4] = extractHOGFeatures(I,'CellSize',[4 4]);

 cellSize = [4 4];
 hogFeatureSize = length(hog_4x4);

 %% Test Images from Test Set 

 NAIRALabel = predict(classifier,hog_4x4);

V%% Map back to training set to find identity 
       personIndex{digit} = trainingSet(i).Description;

 %% 
 booleanIndex = strcmp(NAIRALabel, personIndex);

 integerIndex = find(booleanIndex);

  subplot(1,2,1);imshow(notes);title('Query Face');
   subplot(1,2,2);imshow(read(trainingSet(integerIndex),1));title('Matched Class');
```

ERROR:
.

> Error using imageSet/read (line 307)
>   This method is not supported for arrays of imageSet objects.
>
> Error in hogFeat (line 24)
>   subplot(1,2,2);imshow(read(trainingSet(integerIndex),1));title('Matched Class');

```
 %%%%%%%% updated %%%%%%%

     %  NAIRALabel predicts the right folder which the image is located. 

 %so I did something like this:
 if NAIRALabel = '1';
     imshow(read(image, 1); title(valid  note);
 end

 %But I get this error:

  The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.
```

Is there a way I can make this approach work please?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because `integerIndex` is not a scalar. It is either a multi-element array or empty. I would assume that it is empty because you weren't able to find a match.

As a result when you index into `trainingSet` (using `integerIndex`), you are getting a non-scalar `imageset` object (as the error message states).

Comment: I just tried your code... 'Index exceeds matrix dimension' is now the error.

Comment: This is likely because your integer index is empty.

Comment: Oops... Okay @Suever... What other way can I display the matched image? It already predicts the correct folder of the matched image. How else can I display the image in the matched folder? Please.

Comment: @user6086432 It is hard to say with the small amount of code that you have provided.

Comment: if it won't be too much I could provide all my codes. Can I email to you?

Comment: @user6086432 That's a little much. I would just step through your code line by line with the debugger and see why `integerIndex` is empty.